# Changing SQL Server 2008 recovery mode

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Does anyone have t-sql to change the recovery mode of a database to simple?

We are changing our backup strategy so now I need to bulk change many databases from Full recovery mode and would prefer not to do this one at a time in SSMS.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use [database_name]
alter database  [database_name]
set recovery simple
```